# Metal / Scenekit - Repeating texture on sampler

Tags: scenekit, metal, metalkit

not sure why but I am not able to repeat the texture when using customer fragment shader

Here is my fragment

```
fragment float4 bFragment( VertexOut vertexOut [[stage_in]],
                           texture2d<float, access::sample> textureInput [[texture(0)]],)
    {
constexpr sampler sampler2d(coord::normalized, address::repeat, filter::linear, address::repeat);

float4 outputColor;
outputColor = textureInput.sample(sampler2d, vertexOut.texCoord);

return float4(outputColor.x , outputColor.y , outputColor.z , 1.0);

}
```

Here is how I pass the texture:

```
let imageProperty = SCNMaterialProperty(contents: texture)
imageProperty.wrapS  = .repeat
imageProperty.wrapT  = .repeat
imageProperty.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4MakeScale(screenRatio * numberOfRepetitionsOnX, numberOfRepetitionsOnX , 1)
node.geometry!.firstMaterial!.setValue(imageProperty, forKey: "textureInput")
```

*Image is NOT repeated*, just clamped to the object, no matter the size of the texture.

If I use the same settings with NO customer shader:

```
let myMaterial = SCNMaterial()
myMaterial.lightingModel = .constant
myMaterial.diffuse.contents = texture 
myMaterial.diffuse.wrapS = .repeat
myMaterial.diffuse.wrapT = .repeat
myMaterial.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4MakeScale(screenRatio * numberOfRepetitionsOnX, numberOfRepetitionsOnX , 1)
node.geometry!.firstMaterial! = myMaterial
```

*Texture correctly repeated*

**Questions:**

- What I have to change in order to be effective contentsTransform value also when using the sampler in custom fragment shader?
- If that is not possible, what is the easiest way to achieve that? (Scaling, repeating.redrawing the texture is not an option)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `SCNProgram` the `contentsTransform` property of `SCNMaterialProperty` has no effect (because support is implemented in SceneKit's built-in vertex and fragment shaders).

You will need to pass the 2D matrix to the custom `SCNProgram` shaders and manually transform the texture coordinates there.

Comment: thanks, any doc or example online or here for the same?